# Coloring the cancellation line with \cancel

Tags: math-mode, color, cancel

I would like the strike-out line colored grey when using the `\cancel` command from the `cancel` package.

The code...

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{cancel}

\begin{document}

$$a+\cancel b+c$$

\end{document}
```

... gives this output:

[image]

Can this cancellation line be made weaker in the colour, for example grey, while the math itself remains black?

Comment: Please don't use `$$...$$`, that's deprecated in LaTeX. Use `\[...\]` instead

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I see... Why on Earth would that easy, fool-proof notation form be made appreciated?

Comment: Which one? `$$...$$` isn't fool - proof for LaTeX parsing ;-)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer A bit more accessible for the mortals among us, I will claim. Anyhow, thank you for the answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using `\renewcommand{\CancelColor}{\color{whatevercoloryoulike}}` should help!

I suggest to use the `thicklines` option to the package as well:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[thicklines]{cancel}

\renewcommand{\CancelColor}{\color{lightgray}}

\begin{document}

\[a+\cancel{b}+c\]

\end{document}
```

[image]